# MissingMethodException: "No parameterless constructor for this object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

*Disclaimer: Yes, I've [googled](http://www.google.se/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=no+parameterless+constructor+defined+for+this+object+asp.net+mvc) and read through the top six or so hits, [searched on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+parameterless+constructor+defined+for+this+object%22) and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477518/system-missingmethodexception-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-obje) [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331276/server-error-in-application-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-ob) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547736/asp-net-mvc2-error-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765286/asp-net-mvc-2-ninject-2-2-and-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-obje), but neither of them has helped me resolve this... [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object), and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object/3622372#3622372), seems to come pretty close, but I still can't figure it out. Thus, please bear with me even though I seem to ask a question that has been asked many times before.*

### Question

When I submit a form, I get a `System.MissingMethodException` saying "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." There seems to be a number of different, fairly common, causes for this - the two most prominent being that the Controller lacks a default constructor and doesn't have it's dependencies satisified when the DI framework tries to resolve it, respectively that the input model on the action method doesn't have a default constructor. From my stack trace, I've deduced that the latter seems to be my problem - however, I've come nowhere trying to troubleshoot this.

### Background info

My stack trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
>
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +117
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +247
> System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +106
> System.Web.Mvc.**DefaultModelBinder**.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +243
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +151
> etc... it goes on for a while...

However, my model *does* have a parameterless constructor (see code below)!

My POST action method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddObject(InspectionObjectEditModel input, IUser user)
// IUser is passed with a custom model binder, that is verified to work
```

My GET action method, that shows the form:

```
public ActionResult CreateObject()
{
    var model = GetEditModelForID(0); // Calls new InspectionObjectEditModel()
    model.PostAction = "AddObject";
    return View(model);
}
```

The `InspectionObjectEditModel`:

```
public class InspectionObjectEditModel : ViewModel<InspectionObject, int>, IInspectionObjectData
{
    // ReSharper warns on the constructor, because it's redundant
    public InspectionObjectEditModel() { }

    #region Properties for editing
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("Littera")]
    public virtual string Littera { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Type")]
    public virtual InspectionObjectType Type { get; set; }
    [Required, NotNull]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Owner")]
    public virtual string Owner { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Address")]
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Caretaker")]
    public virtual string Caretaker { get; set; }
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Remarks")]
    public virtual string Remarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_X")]
    public virtual float PlacementX { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Y")]
    public virtual float PlacementY { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayNameLocalized("IInspectionObjectData_Z")]
    public virtual float PlacementZ { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Data for form elements
    public virtual List<InspectionObjectType> Types { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Geocode { get; set; }

    //public Expression<Action<InspectionController>> PostAction { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostAction { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Properties that won't be edited
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual User LastUpdatedByUser { get; set; }
    public IList<InspectionActivity> Activities { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If InspectionObjectType doesn't have a parameterless constructor it may cause that exception. Not only does your model class need a parameterless constructor, I believe the types of its public properties do as well.

edit...

I think you are increasing your chances of problems by using such a complex class for your model. I have always preferred to keep my view models as simple as possible - really simple. You can then use an auto mapper to transfer to a more full featured object, or use aggregation, or if there are only a few properties, just do it property by property in your controller action method.

Comment: `InspectionObjectType` does (in the same, redundant way `InspectionObject` does) have a default constructor. I had this working with interface types before, but just in case - does that mean I can't have `IList<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` etc as property types?

Comment: OK, I solved it by introducing a new InputModel class. I was trying to use the same type for rendering the edit view as for retrieving the changes, which didn't work since some of the referenced types didn't have constructors. I don't want to change them, since this is a pretty big application and I don't want to risk breaking anything, but introducing another viewmodel is OK. The new viewmodel class only has properties for the stuff that will always be there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that some of the types used in this monster domain model don't have default constructors: `InspectionActivity`, `User`, `Project`, `InspectionObjectType` or some of the properties they are referencing, or some of the objects used in the base class  `ViewModel<InspectionObject, int>`. Using view models really would make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to fill a Parameter?
It throw this Exception when you dont have filled all parameters of the Method